Issue with registering custom activation function in tensorflow
I have a code that used to work on Python 3.8. I am trying to port it to 3.11. I can't get the following to work:
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Activation, Dense, Input
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential

def softplus_shifted(x):
    """
    A shifted softplus function = a + exp(x)
    """
    a = 1.2214027581601699  # np.exp(0.20), reducing operations
    return tf.math.log(tf.constant(a, dtype=tf.float32) +
                       tf.math.exp(x))

# Register the activation function
tf.keras.utils.get_custom_objects().update(
    {'softplus_shifted': Activation(softplus_shifted)})

# Build the model
model = Sequential([
    Input(shape=(4,)),
    Dense(10, activation='softplus_shifted')
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
print(model.summary())

I get the following error:

As text:
C:\Users\rghig\Dropbox\sys_strats_rg\.venv\Scripts\python.exe "C:/Program Files/JetBrains/PyCharm Community Edition 2024.1.1/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/pydevconsole.py" --mode=client --host=127.0.0.1 --port=54195 
import sys; print('Python %s on %s' % (sys.version, sys.platform))
sys.path.extend(['C:\\Users\\rghig\\Dropbox\\sys_strats_rg', 'C:\\Users\\rghig\\Dropbox\\sys_strats_rg\\libs', 'C:\\Users\\rghig\\Dropbox\\sys_strats_rg\\tests_functional'])
PyDev console: starting.
Python 3.11.0 (main, Oct 24 2022, 18:26:48) [MSC v.1933 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
runfile('C:\\Users\\rghig\\AppData\\Roaming\\JetBrains\\PyCharmCE2024.1\\scratches\\scratch_2.py', wdir='C:\\Users\\rghig\\AppData\\Roaming\\JetBrains\\PyCharmCE2024.1\\scratches')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2024.1.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\pydevconsole.py", line 364, in runcode
    coro = func()
           ^^^^^^
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2024.1.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_umd.py", line 197, in runfile
    pydev_imports.execfile(filename, global_vars, local_vars)  # execute the script
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2024.1.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:\Users\rghig\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\PyCharmCE2024.1\scratches\scratch_2.py", line 20, in <module>
    Dense(10, activation='softplus_shifted')
  File "C:\Users\rghig\Dropbox\sys_strats_rg\.venv\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\layers\core\dense.py", line 89, in __init__
    self.activation = activations.get(activation)
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\rghig\Dropbox\sys_strats_rg\.venv\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\activations\__init__.py", line 104, in get
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Could not interpret activation function identifier: softplus_shifted

I tried with ChatGPT, but no luck either. Any help would be great! Thank you very much!
FWIW my IDE (PyCharm) says that this from tensorflow.keras.utils import get_custom_objects is an unresolved reference.

Please post the an error as text, not a screenshot
